# Twitter Bootstrap Datepicker startDate & endDate not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, calendar

I have a Twitter Bootstrap datepicker in which I want to disable future dates, I tried the following code

```
$('.calendarControl').datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',       
    endDate: '+0d'
});
```

But I do not see the future dates as disabled, they are getting selected on click. I have downloaded the libraries from [This site](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

can anyone help me with this!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

'endDate' is not a valid option for this library.

You can do something like the code example given, i.e. use the onRender function:

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('.calendarControl').datepicker({
    onRender: function(date) {
      return date.valueOf() > now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
  }
});
```